# HTML box of colour is not showing up

Tags: html, css, web, block

See here: http://ryanteaches.com/gcsechemistry.html

I am trying to get a box of colour sitting just above the black box at the bottom. But I cant seem to get the colour to show for some reason. Have I missed something?

```html
.subscribebox{
 display:block;
 overflow:auto;
 background-color: #dc2b2b
 width:100%;
 height:220px;
 margin-bottom: 220px; 
 position: relative;
```

Cheers, 
Ryan

Comment: bro you gave width to background-color remove that. may be you forgot a semicolon.between background-color and width.

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it was going to be something daft. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a semicolon  -- ; -- after your color is set.

`background-color: #dc2b2b;`

Answer (score 0):

You need HTML. And you missed a semi colon and a closing bracket.

```css
.subscribebox{
 display:block;
 overflow:auto;
 background-color: #dc2b2b;
 width:100%;
 height:220px;
 margin-bottom: 10px; 
 position: relative;
}

.blackbox{
 display:block;
 overflow:auto;
 background-color: black;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribebox"></div>
<div class="blackbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS for your `.subscribebox,` it seems that your `background-color:`  statement has no semi-colon(;) at the end. If you put the semi-colon after the `background-color`, should work like a charm!
Also don't forget the closing bracket(}) after the css statement!
Hope this helps!